# Смена фокуса WebBrowser в WinCE 5.0 при обработке системного Input

Tags: input, webbrowser, embedded, focus

Доброго. Пишу легковесный веб-браузер под WinCE для внутренних нужд. Разумеется, столкнулся с кучей известных CE-шных граблей. С одними из них так и не придумал, что сделать. Ситуация проста, как три копейки - нужно перехватывать событие сканирования штрихкода и пробрасывать штрихкод в инпут на страничке в WebBrowser. Страничка простая, поэтому первое, что пришло в голову, - просто фокуситься на нужном поле и сканить, а WebBrowser отловит системный ивент и положит строку в инпут страницы. Каково же было мое удивление, когда я попробовал это сделать. WebBrowser интерпретирует событие сканирования как ввод в следующий за текущим элемент управления, а не тот, что находится в фокусе. К примеру, если имеем два инпута и кнопку, то при каждом последующем сканировании будет происходить следующее:

1. Ничего. Документ получит фокус.
2. Штрихкод попадет в 1-й инпут, он же получит фокус.
3. Штрихкод попадет во 2-й инпут, он же получит фокус.
4. Штрихкод никуда не попадет, фокус получит кнопка, расположенная под инпутами, и она же словит onclick.
5. Обратно к п.1, и так далее по кругу.

Таким образом, вместо ввода в фокусный элемент, получаем петлю, и при каждом сканировании фокус смещается вниз по дереву страницы на один элемент. Причем ситуация справедлива не только для отдельного контрола, но и для IE (что логично, учитывая, что WebBrowser является его прямым потомком). Как это забороть - не имею понятия.. Кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поведение при вставке штрихкода можно задать в настройках. В моем случае был задан символ, предшествующий вставке, - табуляция. Убрал, теперь поведение при сканировании предсказуемо.